# Make sounds in alsa with interrupts of cores

Tags: c, audio, interrupt, alsa

Hi, I'm making a laboratory for my university, and I am trying to use Alsa software to make sounds for the quantity of interrupts that I have in 1 loop. The values to store on Alsa buffer are mostly like 0,1,2 occasionally a 4 or 5 (I calculate the differences of interrupts between loops). I found a program that makes a sinusoidal wave, and makes a continuous beep, I want to transform that wave into a wave of interrupts, can anyone help?

In this first code, I'm trying to make that alsa make a sounds when interrupts are != 0, or don't make any sound if interrupts is == 0.

```
int playback_callback (snd_pcm_sframes_t nframes)
{
    static float t = 0;
    int err;
    unsigned long long ti = 0, ti1 = 0, diff = 0,secs = 0;

    ti = ti1 = num_interrupts();

    printf ("playback callback called with %lu frames\n", nframes);

    for(int i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; ++i) {
       /*num_interrupts: function to calculate interrupts on /proc/interrupts*/
       ti = num_interrupts();
       diff = ti-ti1;
       ti1 = ti;
       /*printf("diff%llu\n",diff);*/
       if(diff != 0) {
           buf[i] = 65535;
       } else {
           buf[i] = 0;          
       }
    }
    if ((err = snd_pcm_writei (playback_handle, buf, nframes)) < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "write failed (%s)\n", snd_strerror (err));
    }

    return err;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The human ear does not hear individual samples; it hears *frequencies*.

You should generate a sine wave (or more than one) and modulate its volume and/or frequency based on the interrupt rate.

Please note that very quick changes are not audible; you should check the interrupt numbers only about every 3000 samples.